# Does a loop.run_in_executor functions need asyncio.lock() or threading.Lock()?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing, python-asyncio

I copied the following code for my project and it's worked quite well for me but I don't really understand how the following code runs my blocking_function:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):  
      loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
      block_response = await loop.run_in_executor(ThreadPoolExecutor(), blocking_function)
```

where on_message is called every time I receive a message. If I receive multiple messages, they are processed asynchronously.

blocking_function is a synchronous function that I don't want to be run when another blocking_function is running.Then within blocking_function, should I use threading.Lock() or asyncio.lock()?

Comment: If `blocking_function` isn’t defined with `async def` you can’t use `async` or `await` in it, so you have to using `threading.Lock`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by dirn in the comment, in `blocking_function` you cannot use an `asyncio.Lock` because it's just not async. (The opposite also applies: you cannot lock a `threading.Lock` from an async function because attempting to do so would block the event loop.) If you need to guard data accessed by other instances of `blocking_function`, you should use a `threading.Lock`.

> but I don't really understand how the following code runs my `blocking_function`

It hands off `blocking_function` to the thread pool you created to run it. The thread pool queues and runs the function (which happens "in the background" from your perspective), and the `run_in_executor` arranges the event loop to be notified when the function is done, handing off its return value as the result of the `await` expression.

Note that you should use `None` as the first argument of `run_in_executor`. If you use `ThreadPoolExecutor()`, you create a whole new thread pool for each message, and you never dispose of it. A thread pool is normally meant to be created once, and reuse a fixed number ("pool") of threads for subsequent work. `None` tells asyncio to use the thread pool it creates for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can easily achieve your desired objective by ensuring a single thread is used.

A simple solution would be to ensure that all calls to `blocking_function` is run on a single thread. This can be easily achieved by creating a `ThreadPoolExecutor` object with 1 worker outside of the async function. Then every subsequent calls to the blocking function will be run on that single thread

```
thread_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
@client.event
async def on_message(message):  
      loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
      block_response = await loop.run_in_executor(thread_pool, blocking_function)
```

Don't forget to shutdown the thread afterwards.